# Use string "array[n]" as variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I dont know how to really explain this, but here my problem.

i have a string `"myKey[2]"` and i want to

```
const values = {
 "myKey": ["hey", "oh"],
 "b": ["something"]
};

const str = "myKey[2]";
```

My question is  : how to get `"oh"` with a string as a variable name + is there something in js who can read `"myarray.key"` as variable too without apply many regex and function ?

Comment: What about just using `const str = values.myKey[2]`? Otherwise you will need to use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), which is highly discouraged and dangerous.

Comment: Sadly I can only get this variable as a string and `values["myKey[2]"]` return undefined

Comment: That's because it should be `values.myKey[2]` or `values['myKey'][2]`

Comment: I can only get this "variable" as a string

Comment: Feels like an XY problem to me. Why are you storing an accessor as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the indexing for the array starts from zero, accessing "myKey[2]" will give you undefined.Assuming you want to take the second element from the array,we can do

```js
const values = {
 "myKey": ["hey", "oh"],
 "b": ["something"]
};

const str = "myKey[1]";

const result=values[str.slice(0, str.indexOf('['))][
  Number(str.slice(str.indexOf('[') + 1, str.indexOf(']')))
];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string should be

`const str = values.myKey[1];`

or if your key has dashes and such

`const str = values['myKey'][1];`

Keep in mind that the right index in this case is **1**, not **2** as the index numbering in arrays starts from **0** and not **1**.